# Ubuntu is not booting up (From a fresh install)

Tags: 18.04, ssd, external-hdd, bios

Laptop: Acer swift 3, intel core i5 6200-U

TL;DR
Tried installing ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from an install drive (usb) into my Samsung T5 SSD
I've tried installing it multiple times but I keep getting the same result, a black screen.

I've been trying to install ubuntu for the past five hours. Every time I try to boot it from the BIOS, for a split second the screen shows a " _ " and then it either goes into a black screen until the laptop goes to sleep, or a few seconds after the black screen it boots up to windows.

The process I followed started off installing it as "Something else" then selecting the sdb and making a new partition table, after that in the sdb I created a partition with: 150.000MB, Primaray, beginning of this space, ext4 journaling file system, /. As for the device for boot loader installation I selected the SSD and then proceeded to install. 
At the start the ssd didn't appear in the BIOS but after changing the booting mode from UEFI to Legacy it appeared as an option to boot from. While doing this I also changed the booting priority order and put USB HDD first.
For reinstall processes I edited the existing partition put the same parameters as before and also selecting the "format the partition" box.

I tried opening the GRUB terminal by holding the right  shift before, after, and while I'm in the BOOT MANAGER screen, but haven't managed to open it.

Comment: Runned the boot-repair from the ubuntu live usb
 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3R76pvRRXj/

Comment: Using commands trying to install the grub grub and the following error shows up: grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS boot partition; embedding won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of doing the whole download thing in my computer, i went to my school and try downloading it in one of theirs and it just decided to work now. So after all my laptop was the problem